# Sorting a text file which contains integers, sorting has to be done line by line

Tags: c++, algorithm, file, sorting, concurrency

I want to sort a file which contains integers but wanted to sort only line by line. I tried, but I am sure what I am doing below isn't in-place.

```
void sort_file_in_place(const char* filename) {
    fstream sort_file;
    sort_file.open(filename, ios::out | ios::in);
    vector <vector <int> > input_vect;
    string line;
    std::string delimiter = " ";
    int vect_index = 0;
    while (getline(cin, line)) {
        //store into vector of vectors
        //tokenise string 
        size_t pos = 0;
        int value = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while ((pos = line.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
            string token = line.substr(0, pos);
            line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
            value = std::atoi(token.c_str());
            count++;
        }
        input_vect.resize(vect_index++, vector<int>(count));
    }
    //sort vector of vectors
    for (int i = 0; i < input_vect.size(); i++) {
        sort(input_vect[i].begin(), input_vect[i].end(), std::less<int>());
        //print the sorted vectors and alos verify the content 
        for (auto v : input_vect[i]) cout << v << " ";
    }
    //write back into the file
    //Todo
}
```

The above code isn't complete but I hope you get what I wanted to ask.

Please suggest a better solution.

Also I want to sort these lines using different threads, for example:

If the file content is:

> 13 38 13 100 4 234 85 34 0 100 88
>
> 1 4 5 3 8 9 1 10
>
> 111 10 112 3 4 098 194
>
> 5 4 8 3 9 13 24 78 09 99

I want to create four threads to sort each line in-place.

Comment: Please only ask one question. Right now there are multiple: "How can I sort integers line-by-line in a file?" and "How can I run an algorithm on another thread?", (and debatably a third: "How can I divide an algorithm's work among four threads?")

Comment: should i edit this question?

Comment: Study up on "merge sort".  The merge sort was an excellent sort for files (and tape drives).

Comment: Please provide the definition of [in-place](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) for this question.

Comment: There is an overhead to managing threads. As of 2019, I'd expect the number of primitive values (`integers`) to sort needed for threading to be helpful to be in the thousands.

Comment: Once a line (a set of values to be put in order with no regard to other input) is read, it can be sorted right away.

Comment: `hope you get what I wanted to ask` No. I'm left with the impression that you dumped an assignment.

Comment: You are using std::sort which works in-place. Your code looks OK, what improvements do you have in mind?

Comment: @greybeard sorry for late reply. in-place i meant, we shouldn't take a buffer like i did (copying into a vector, sorting and then writing it back to file), and sort those lines of integers then and there, can that be done at all!?

Comment: Hi @denniskb i am using another buffer, please see above reply. thanks for your time reading my code

Comment: @Amaresh you can't avoid the buffer, you can't sort 'directly inside a text file'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot see how to do it *"in-place"*. Perhaps with some black magic we could sort elements without having them somewhere in memory but I don't have knowledge about such an occult science :)

Joking aside, if storing the lines into a `std::vector` does not suit your needs, you can use any other container you may want, even a raw array or a custom one. But in any case, you have to store the lines somewhere to handle them (to sort them in this case).

---

I have written an example to achieve what you want:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string & s, char c)
{
    std::vector<std::string> splitted;

    std::string word;
    for(char ch : s)
    {
        if((ch == c) && (!word.empty()))
        {
            splitted.push_back(word);
            word.clear();
        }
        else
            word += ch;
    }
    if(!word.empty())
        splitted.push_back(word);

    return splitted;
}
bool read_data(const std::string & file_path, std::vector<std::vector<int>> & data)
{
    data.clear();

    std::ifstream in_s(file_path);
    if(!in_s)
        return false;

    std::string line;
    std::vector <int> row;
    while(std::getline(in_s, line))
    {
        if(!line.empty())
        {
            for(auto s : split(line, ' '))
                row.push_back(std::stoi(s));
            data.push_back(row);
            row.clear();
        }
    }

    in_s.close();
    return true;
}
bool write_data(const std::string & file_path, const std::vector<std::vector<int>> & data)
{
    std::ofstream out_s(file_path);
    if(!out_s)
        return false;

    for(const auto & row : data)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < row.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(i == 0)
                out_s << row[i];
            else
            {
                out_s << ((row[i] < 0) ? (" ") : ("  ")) << row[i];
            }
        }
        out_s << std::endl;
    }

    out_s.close();
    return true;
}
void sort_line(std::vector<int> & line)
{
    std::sort(line.begin(), line.end(), [](const int & i, const int & j){return i<j;});
}
void sort_data_lines(std::vector<std::vector<int>> & data)
{
    std::vector<std::thread> thread_mem;

    for(auto & row : data)
    {
        thread_mem.push_back(std::thread(sort_line, std::ref(row)));
    }

    for(auto & t : thread_mem)
        t.join();
}
```

I have separated the code in three main functions, `read_data()` to read data from a file, `sort_data_lines()` to sort the data and `write_data()` to write data into a file.

It may be used as follows:

```
int main()
{
    const std::string in_file_path("path/to/the/input_file.txt");
    const std::string out_file_path("path/to/the/output_file.txt");

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;
    if(!read_data(in_file_path, data))   // Read the data
        return -1;

    sort_data_lines(data);               // Sort the data

    if(!write_data(out_file_path, data)) // Write the sorted data
        return -2;

    return 0;
}
```

I have multi-threaded the sorting of each line (as asked) but I think it may be important to notice that it is not a good idea if your file contains a lot of lines (and consequently, a lot of simultaneously running threads).
Usually, fix a limit at between 4 and 8 running threads is a good choice.
Of course, if your file is supposed to contain only four lines, there is no problem since you'll only have 4 running threads :)

---

I've made the test with the following input file:

```
5  2  4  3  1 -3  8 -4 -1  0  1  0  6
6  9  3  1  5  2  6  8 -7 -1  0  0 -3
2  7  9  3  4  5 -5  6 -1  0  2 -2  3
0 -6 -2  8  5 -1  4  5 -6  7  2  2  0
```

And I obtained the following output file:

```
-4 -3 -1  0  0  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  8
-7 -3 -1  0  0  1  2  3  5  6  6  8  9
-5 -2 -1  0  2  2  3  3  4  5  6  7  9
-6 -6 -2 -1  0  0  2  2  4  5  5  7  8
```

Hope it can help a bit.